# Install Application programmatically on Android without deleting DB and shared pref file

Tags: android, installation

I am trying to update an apk file programmatically, But due to versionCode & versionName, its not installing. Can any one please guide me to update the apk file prograammatically such that
I can able to install apk programmatically. I followed the steps mentioned at 
[Android: install .apk programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically/4969421#4969421)

Comment: Its not installing? what error does it give?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution for the above issue:

android:versionName — A string value that represents the release version of the application code, as it should be shown to users.

The value is a string so that you can describe the application version as a .. string, or as any other type of absolute or relative version identifier.

[For more info see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/versioning.html)